# how i can do sync requests?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Сan not understand how to make synchron request in thread and don't block request in another thread. My code:

```
for (Obj obj: objects) {
       Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
       try {
          res = hDownloadUrl(obj.url, null); // always whait before get query from another thread
          newUrl = res.getUrl();
          res2 = hDownloadUrl(obj.url, null);
          //  ..............

       } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

where hDownloadUrl:

```
   public InputStream hDownloadUrl(String urlString, String userAgent) throws IOException {
        Log.w("Helper hDownloadUrl: ", urlString);
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        if (userAgent != null){
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
        }
        conn.connect();
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? What do you mean by "don't block request in another thread"? Do you want to send more than one request asynchronously in parallel? If so, how did you send the first request, the async one?

Comment: i have a lot of thread where in other of thread make requests in (thread they shoud be syncon, becouse i need get next url from before request) but my code don't do it asyncron, at one time performed only one request

Comment: HOW do you do the asynchronous call? Please share that code.

Comment: Threads are costly to create and destroy.  If your program continually creates new threads, then you probably could improve its performance by using a _thread pool_  such as `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @Hermann Klecker but i show you - new Thread(..)

Comment: Again, what exactly is your problem? You create a thread in which you fire a request and get its result. You have to wait for the result. The result contains the URL for some subsequent request which you then fire on the same thread. That looks good to me. It is just that there is no such thing like "another tread" because all of that is done on the same thread but not  on the main thread. So what do you want to change and why?

Comment: When first thread start their first hDownloadUrl() another tread 
trying start their  hDownloadUrl() but second thread can't do this because seems like hDownloadUrl is blocked and wait when finish first request. This is my problem, second thread should not wait...